# Error when attempting to get XML data

Tags: php, xml

I am working on the Amazon API, and when I get a responce it looks like this.

```
<GetMatchingProductForIdResult Id="082686322638" IdType="UPC" status="Success">
<Products>
  <Product>
    <Identifiers>
      <MarketplaceASIN>
        <MarketplaceId>ATVPDKIKX0DER</MarketplaceId>
        <ASIN>B00TU53O8Q</ASIN>
      </MarketplaceASIN>
    </Identifiers>
    <AttributeSets>
      <ns2:ItemAttributes xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd" xml:lang="en-US">
        <ns2:Binding>Toy</ns2:Binding>
        <ns2:Brand>Rubie's</ns2:Brand>
        <ns2:Color>BLACK</ns2:Color>
        <ns2:Department>unisex-child</ns2:Department>
        <ns2:Feature>Half Helmet mask accessory covers face; one size fits most</ns2:Feature>
        <ns2:Feature>Officially licensed Star Wars Episode VII costume accessory; as worn by Kylo Ren in Star Wars Episode VII: The Force Awakens</ns2:Feature>
        <ns2:Feature>Helmet has faux battle damage representing a pivotal moment in the movie</ns2:Feature>
        <ns2:Feature>Kylo Ren costumes and additional accessories available separately</ns2:Feature>
        <ns2:Feature>Rubie's offers costumes and accessories from Star Wars original and prequel trilogies as well as the Clone Wars series; great group and family costume ideas</ns2:Feature>
        <ns2:ItemDimensions>
          <ns2:Height Units="inches">10.00</ns2:Height>
          <ns2:Length Units="inches">10.00</ns2:Length>
          <ns2:Width Units="inches">10.00</ns2:Width>
          <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">0.13</ns2:Weight>
        </ns2:ItemDimensions>
        <ns2:IsAdultProduct>false</ns2:IsAdultProduct>
        <ns2:Label>Rubies - Domestic</ns2:Label>
        <ns2:ListPrice>
          <ns2:Amount>9.99</ns2:Amount>
          <ns2:CurrencyCode>USD</ns2:CurrencyCode>
        </ns2:ListPrice>
        <ns2:Manufacturer>Rubies - Domestic</ns2:Manufacturer>
        <ns2:ManufacturerMaximumAge Units="months">120.0</ns2:ManufacturerMaximumAge>
        <ns2:ManufacturerMinimumAge Units="months">60.0</ns2:ManufacturerMinimumAge>
        <ns2:Model>32263</ns2:Model>
        <ns2:NumberOfItems>1</ns2:NumberOfItems>
        <ns2:PackageDimensions>
          <ns2:Height Units="inches">4.00</ns2:Height>
          <ns2:Length Units="inches">9.20</ns2:Length>
          <ns2:Width Units="inches">8.20</ns2:Width>
          <ns2:Weight Units="pounds">0.15</ns2:Weight>
        </ns2:PackageDimensions>
        <ns2:PackageQuantity>1</ns2:PackageQuantity>
        <ns2:PartNumber>32263</ns2:PartNumber>
        <ns2:ProductGroup>Toy</ns2:ProductGroup>
        <ns2:ProductTypeName>TOYS_AND_GAMES</ns2:ProductTypeName>
        <ns2:Publisher>Rubies - Domestic</ns2:Publisher>
        <ns2:Size>One Size</ns2:Size>
        <ns2:SmallImage>
          <ns2:URL>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41XuPVJMMkL._SL75_.jpg</ns2:URL>
          <ns2:Height Units="pixels">75</ns2:Height>
          <ns2:Width Units="pixels">66</ns2:Width>
        </ns2:SmallImage>
        <ns2:Studio>Rubies - Domestic</ns2:Studio>
        <ns2:Title>Star Wars: The Force Awakens Child's Kylo Ren Half Helmet</ns2:Title>
        <ns2:Warranty>No Warranty</ns2:Warranty>
      </ns2:ItemAttributes>
    </AttributeSets>
    <Relationships/>
    <SalesRankings>
      <SalesRank>
        <ProductCategoryId>toy_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
        <Rank>5183</Rank>
      </SalesRank>
      <SalesRank>
        <ProductCategoryId>2229575011</ProductCategoryId>
        <Rank>11</Rank>
      </SalesRank>
    </SalesRankings>
  </Product>
</Products>
</GetMatchingProductForIdResult>
```

How do i go about getting the Sales Rank, Amount, Product Dims, Id, and ASIN?
I have been looking around for some time now, and haven't found anything about the colon.

My code that i was trying to use is:

```
for($i = 0; $i < (count($groupedArrays) - 0); $i++){
    $xmlFilePath = 'xml/' . $file_name . $i . '.xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFilePath);

foreach($xml->children() as $items) { 
    if ($items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Error) {
        continue;
    }
    $upcTag = $items['Id'] . ',';
    if($items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Products->Product->AttributeSets->Relationship == FALSE){
        echo $items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Products->Product->AttributeSets->SalesRankings->SalesRank[0] . ',';
    } else {
        echo  $items->GetMatchingProductForIdResult->Products->Product->AttributeSets->Relationship->VariationParent->Identifiers->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN . ',';
    }
        $subject = "<ns2:Amount></ns2:Amount>";
        preg_match_all('/<[^:]*:([^>]*)>(.*)<\/[^>]*>/', $subject, $matches);

$i = 1;
$ii = 0;
foreach ($matches as $key => $value) {          
   $newArr[$matches[$i][$ii]] = $matches[$ii][$ii];            
   $ii++;
   $i++;
}

$result = array_filter($newArr); 
foreach($result as $key => $value){
echo $key." = ".$value. "<br/>";
};
}
```

There is a for loop before this one that gets the response and saves it as a .xml in my xml folder. i cannot figure out what i am doing wrong and help would be greatly appreciated! I have been working on this part for a little more then 8-9 hours. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the properties from your xml, you can use [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php).

To loop the `<ns2:ItemAttributes..` you can use the SimpleXMLElement [children](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) method with the corresponding namespace 'ns2'

Maybe this example which gets a few of the properties can help you:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFilePath);
$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);

$asin = '';
$salesRankings = array();
$amount = '';

foreach ($xml->Products->Product as $product) {
    $asin = (string)$product->Identifiers->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN;

    foreach ($product->SalesRankings->SalesRank as $salesRank) {
        $salesRankings[] = array(
            "ProductCategoryId" => (string)$salesRank->ProductCategoryId,
            "Rank" => (string)$salesRank->Rank
        );
    }
    foreach ($product->AttributeSets->children($ns['ns2']) as $itemAttributes) {
        $amount = (string)$itemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code did not work. I am not sure what i am doing wrong. When i run this code it gives me a bunch of warnings. I am not sure what is going on. Could you possibly just write it off of my current code?

Comment: @Robert The code is based on the provided xml in the question. You can see the result in this [demo](https://3v4l.org/3e3Qv) (note that in the demo I've used [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) instead of [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php). What are the warnings that you get? Is the structure of the xml the same when you get the warnings?)

Comment: it was multiple warnings, but only one error, it said "fatal error call to undefined function getNamespace() on line 121". Line 121 is the line that $ns is being defined. When i print something, it doesn't print out anything. I was putting the print inside of the for loop. Since this code overwrites, how would i be able to save everything down to a csv file? I also just realized that you did use simplexm_load_string. So all i would have to do is change that to simplexml_load_file?

Comment: I used simplexml_load_string for the demo to load the string in `$source`. If I look at your code, you want to load xml file(s). Maybe [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) returns false when loading the xml. What you could do is verify if `$xmlFilePath` contains the expected value when the error occurs. When you run the code, is the xml structure in the xml file(s) the same as the xml from your example?

Comment: it returns the everything as expected.